# Idempotent hash associations

Tags: python, hash

I have some names: `["James", "John", "Krieg"]` and some colors: `["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]`. I want to map names to colors, using some hashing function: `f(name) -> color`. This association is idempotent. For example, if in the original list, `f(James) -> Red`, then after I add names or colors to their respective lists, `f(James)` remains `Red`.

Example:

List state 1:

```
["James", "John", "Krieg"] and ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]: 
    f(James) -> Red
    f(John) -> Yellow 
    f(Krieg) -> Yellow
```

List state 2:

```
["James", "John", "Krieg", "Sarah"] and ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Black"]: 
(added "Sarah" and "Black")
    f(James) -> Red
    f(John) -> Yellow 
    f(Krieg) -> Yellow
    f(Sarah) -> Green
```

The specifics of the hash function are not important as long as it attempts uniformity. I had this question because I have a list of names displayed to a user, and as that list grows, I want the color associations of names previously entered to be the same (so the user retains name/color associations). I realized that if I specified the list of colors in advance, this wouldn't be a problem.

So now it's just out of curiosity -- are there hashing functions which do not change the value of previous associations as input/output sizes grow, without persistence? Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: Why are both "John" and "Krieg" associated with "Yellow" instead of "Green" and "Blue"? I.e. what are the rules by which the associations are constructed?

Comment: Please elaborate; it is unfortunately very hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: why complicate things? Just build a dictionary. It's fast and consistent

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase the question as my original question was terribly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say that such a thing does not exist without relying on persistence.

We can rule out any mapping based on list position.  Let's start with N names and 1 color - that means that all names map to a single color.  If we later have N names and M colors, unless we can store which N names map to that first color, there's no way to make this work.

Likewise, we can rule out anything based on the values of the names/colors.  Assume we have some function f(name, color), which provides the score by which to decide the best color for a name.  If F(bob, green) > F(bob, red) then we end up with a different mapping when our lists go from `[bob], [red]` to `[bob], [green, red]`.

You could come up with some degenerate solutions to this that don't explicitly "save each association" but still persist enough state to recreate the calculation.  At best, these would be storing as much data as simply storing your mapping.  At worst, they're going to store far more.

The use of idempotent suggest that your original question may be abstract curiosity.  If there's a particular, practical, problem you're trying to solve, a more concrete explanation of the issue would help.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that if F(bob, green) > F(bob, red), that relation could change if the list goes from [bob], [red] to [bob], [green, red]? My question was really hard to understand but I think you nailed the intent.

Comment: `F(bob, green) > F(bob, red)` means that given `(bob, (red, green))` as inputs, `green` gets picked.  If you have `(bob, (red))`, you must map `bob` to `red`.  Unless you persist state, there's no way to tell, when choosing a mapping for `(bob, (red, green))`, if you've already assigned `bob` to `red` or you should prefer `green`.

If you're going to persist state, you might as well just store the mapping, unless you can come up with a concrete technical reason that doing so is unfeasible.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that you just need to store the associations in memory. What you need is such an association set that is mutable. In python, this is a dictionary:

```
>>> assocs = dict(zip(['James', 'John', 'Krieg', 'Sarah'], ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow']))
>>> assocs['Sarah']
'Yellow'
>>> assocs['Sarah'] = 'Black'
>>> assocs['Sarah']
'Black'
```

**EDIT**

If you always have the two lists, and they are always in order, then why not use list indices to "store" the mapping:

```
>>> names = ['James', 'John', 'Krieg', 'Sarah']
>>> colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow']
>>> def finmap(name):
... i = names.index(name)
... if i < len(colors):
...     return colors[i]
... else:
...     print 'all the colors have been assigned'
...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I know what a dictionary is. My question is if there's a way to do this without explicitly defining the associations.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the question the first time around. See edit

Comment: Without storing it in memory, or without **keeping** it in memory? It **must** pass through memory on its way to some other device...

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "an on-the-fly way to do it", but I think an idempotent dictionary might help. For example:

```
##!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

class idempotent_dict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            return
        super(idempotent_dict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = idempotent_dict()

    d['James'] = 'Red'
    d['John'] = 'Yellow'
    d['Krieg'] = 'Yellow'

    print d

    d['James'] = 'Black'
    d['John'] = 'Red'
    d['Sarah'] = 'Green'

    print d
```

This prints:

```
{'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Yellow', 'Krieg': 'Yellow'}
{'Sarah': 'Green', 'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Yellow', 'Krieg': 'Yellow'}`
```

Comment: But given the OP's examples, it seems it must be possible to add a new color without adding a new name. I don't see how that's possible here.

Comment: I agree with @senderle on the point about being able to add names and colors independently of one another, however TOTAL PROPS for using super(), since it solved another problem I was having. I always kick my own behind when I realize that I've been working for hours to re-invent something in the Built-in Functions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want an object that will take a list of keys and a list of values (either of any or no length) and return a dictionary that always has the same values regardless of any additions.

```
>>> class ListOMatic(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.people = []
        self.colors = []

    def idpt(self, people=[], colors=[]):

        for p in people:
            if not p in self.people:
                self.people.append(p)

        for c in colors:
            if not c in self.colors:
                self.colors.append(c)

        return dict(zip(self.people, self.colors))

>>> lom = ListOMatic()
>>> people = ['James', 'John', 'Krieg']
>>> colors = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow']
>>> # populate it with our initial values and show that we can pull values out.
>>> print (lom.idpt(people, colors))
{'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue'}
>>> print (lom.idpt())
{'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue'}
>>> print (lom.idpt()["James"])
Red
>>> # add some colors but no names.
>>> print (lom.idpt([],["Purple", "Mauve"]))
{'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue'}
>>> print (lom.idpt())
{'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue'}
>>> # add a name and show that it "picks up" the first available color
>>> print (lom.idpt(["Sarah"],[]))
{'Sarah': 'Yellow', 'James': 'Red', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue'}
>>> print (lom.idpt(["Victor", "Charlie"],["Puce"]))
{'Sarah': 'Yellow', 'James': 'Red', 'Charlie': 'Mauve', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue', 'Victor': 'Purple'}
>>> print (lom.idpt())
{'Sarah': 'Yellow', 'James': 'Red', 'Charlie': 'Mauve', 'John': 'Green', 'Krieg': 'Blue', 'Victor': 'Purple'}
>>> print (lom.idpt()["Sarah"])
Yellow
>>>
```

Hopefully this is what you meant by "on the fly".

Comment: And yes, I had to go google "idempotent" /me hangs head in shame.

Comment: If you don't want to keep the values in memory, I'd suggest taking a look at yaml. You could store the lists on disk, write any updates to the lists as needed, then return the dictionary. It'd be way slow, though. What is this for, if I may ask?

Comment: @lysdexia, this seems like a step in the right direction, but I don't see how it can produce the initial state described in the OP's example.

Comment: @senderle: I see what you mean. I was operating under the assumption that the parings (I think you are probably alluding to John and Krieg both being "Yellow") had already been created, and that the two new lists were not the primary inputs. My example should keep the initial spate fed to it and create new parings as values are added. I don't see any comments from @jasie about it, so I can't really know if this was helpful or not.

Comment: @lysdexia, yes, it's a strange problem isn't it? +1 by the way -- as I stole from you in my answer :)

Comment: @senderle: I did _not_ see what you meant. Yes, to fit the problem better, idpt() should just append any values to colors. Your use of queues is nice.

Answer (score 2):

After giving this a silly amount of thought, I believe that Sean McSomething is right: you can't have *exactly* what you've asked for without "persistence" (but see ** below). The problem is that if you disallow "persistence," then *either* you can have multiple keys map to the same value, *or* you can have each key and each value appear only once in each list, but not both.

That said, here's a class that appears to generate exactly the associations you want, differing only from your example in that it allows multiple identical values, as long as they're entered as part of a single operation. I've appropriated the basic design of [lysdexia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220144/idempotent-hash-associations/6220563#6220563), using queues to manage situations where an unpaired new key maps to a previously inserted value, or vice-versa. There are a lot of problems with the below code, but it does what you asked for; and it was a fun exercise:

```
import itertools

class IdempotentMap(object):
    def __init__(self, keys=[], vals=[]):
        self.keys = []
        self.vals = []
        self.keyqueue = []
        self.valqueue = []
        self.append(keys, vals)

    def has_key(self, key):
        return key in self.keys or key in self.keyqueue

    def has_val(self, val):
        return val in self.vals or val in self.valqueue

    def append(self, keys=[], vals=[]):
        len_diff = len(keys) - len(vals)
        if len_diff > 0:
            vals.extend([None] * len_diff)
        elif len_diff < 0:
            keys.extend([None] * abs(len_diff))
        seen = set()
        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            if k in seen:
                keys[i] = None
            seen.add(k)
        keys = (None if self.has_key(k) else k for k in keys)
        vals = (None if self.has_val(v) else v for v in vals)
        for key, val in zip(keys, vals):
            if key and val:
                self.keys.append(key)
                self.vals.append(val)
            elif key and val is None:
                if self.valqueue:
                    self.keys.append(key)
                    self.vals.append(self.valqueue.pop(0))
                else:
                    self.keyqueue.append(key)
            elif val and key is None:
                if self.keyqueue:
                    self.vals.append(val)
                    self.keys.append(self.keyqueue.pop(0))
                else:
                    self.valqueue.append(val)

    def __iter__(self):
        return ((key, val) for key, val in itertools.izip(self.keys, self.vals))
```

Here's how you use it, with a little flourish at the end to show that keys are always unique:

```
idem = IdempotentMap()
idem.append(['James'], ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'])
print tuple((key, val) for key, val in idem)
idem.append(['John', 'Krieg'], ['Yellow', 'Yellow'])
print tuple((key, val) for key, val in idem)
idem.append(['Sarah', 'Sarah', 'Bo-barah'])
print tuple((key, val) for key, val in idem)
```

Here's the output:

```
(('James', 'Red'),)
(('James', 'Red'), ('John', 'Yellow'), ('Krieg', 'Yellow'))
(('James', 'Red'), ('John', 'Yellow'), ('Krieg', 'Yellow'), ('Sarah', 'Green'), ('Bo-barah', 'Blue'))
```

---

** I put persistence in scare quotes because I think there's some question as to what "persistence" actually means here, given that hashes have to be *calculated*, and the only persistence in a hash table is the cached hash value, if there is one. I'm not certain the associations in a dict are any more "persistent" than the associations in an explicitly index-based mapping such as this one or lysdexia's. They're *both* index-based, in the end, aren't they? *But*, I suppose the above will use less memory for large maps than a dict of comparable size.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `f("Sarah") == "Black"` once you've extended your set of values. The question remains, what was the value of `f("Sarah")` before you'd extended your values? If it was `"Black"` then the result of your hash function doesn't fall within the set of acceptable values. If it's not `"Black"` then your hash function doesn't maintain its mapping as you extend the sets. Your hash function would need to remember the value it gave to any given key, and you're stuck with a map at that point. Which I don't think is a bad solution. But it's not really a hash function anymore.